# Install EXE and specify directory in C#

Tags: c#, startprocessinfo

How do I specify in C# where to install a specific program? I tried using .WorkingDirectory but it didn't work. I want to install the Notepad++ installer inside the NotepadFolder in Desktop, how do I do that?

```
    static void LaunchInstaller()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\UserOne\Downloads\npp.6.1.5.Installer.exe";
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\UserOne\Desktop\NotepadFolder";
        //The line above doesn't work. Notepad++ still installs to its current directory, in ProgramFiles
        startInfo.Arguments = "/S";
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

I saw the code below at [dotnetperls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start). They didn't specify the use of the two strings and its arguments so I'm confuse right now:

```
static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
{
const string ex1 = "C:\\";
const string ex2 = "C:\\Dir";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "dcm2jpg.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;

try
{
    Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)
    {
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch{}
}
```

Comment: You might also find this page interesting: http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

Comment: I also tried using the code provided by dotnetperls thinking that ex1 is the location of installer and ex2 is the destination to be installed. It still doesn't work. I 'll just switch to my original code. Can anyone point me what's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woohoo! Thank you for spenders link, my code works! You just have to add /D=your installation directory in the Arguments.. Here's my updated code:

```
    static void LaunchInstaller()
    {
        const string installdir = @"C:\Users\UserOne\Desktop\NotepadFolder";

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\UserOne\Downloads\npp.6.1.5.Installer.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/S /D=" + installdir; //My new code
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not really programming related and I'm voting to close... In the meantime...

It's authored with Nullsoft Install System v2.46.

Take a look at [the docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#3.2.1).

Comment: What? I'm using C# to create a console application that calls an installer, I think that's programming..

Comment: Yeah, but that's not really your question. Your question is "Where can I find more info about the npp installer options". You don't seem to be struggling with the programming side of things.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That really helps. I'll just remove the arguments part in my post.